# R: How far does it go? (Plus venting)

Tags: r, scope, functional-programming, symbols, evaluation

I have an object called `defaultPacks`, containing the names of packages installed on all the computers I use. Much abbreviated:

```
defaultPacks <- c(
  "AER",
  "plyr",
  "dplyr" 
)
```

I want to save this object to file in a shared directory all of them can reach. I am using Dropbox for this, with sync always paused when R is running.

```
save(defaultPacks, 
file.path("C:","Users","andrewH","Dropbox","R_PROJ","sharedSettings.rdata"))
```

Then I want to load the object and install the packages the names of which are in the object `defaultPacks`.

```
SyncPacks <- function(fileString){
  defaultPacks <- load(file=fileString)
  install.packages(defaultPacks, repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
}
SyncPacks(file.path("C:","Users","andrewH","Dropbox","R_PROJ","sharedSettings.rdata")
```

If I do this, I get a warning:

```
Warning in install.packages: package ‘defaultPacks’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I look what is in `defaultPacks` immediately after I load and assign it: the string `"defaultPacks"`. So it seems to loading just be a string rather than an object.

So I go back to my save, and try

```
save(get(defaultPacks), file.path(etc.))
```

This gives me an different error:

```
Error in save(get("defaultPacks"), file = file.path("C:", "Users", "andrewH",  : 
  object ‘get("defaultPacks")’ not found.
```

Then I tried `dynGet()` with the same result.

So where before it was treating a symbol as a string, now it is treating a function as a string.

So I try the list option for save:

```
save(list = defaultPacks, file = file.path(etc))
```

And get yet another error:

```
Error in save(list = defaultPacks, file = file.path("C:", "Users", "andrewH",  : 
  objects ‘AER’, ‘plyr’, ‘dplyr’, (etc.) not found
```

So where before I couldn't get *to* my character vector, now I am shooting right *past* it, evaluating `defaultPacks` to find the strings, and then treating each string as a symbol, and evaluating it to its (nonexistent) object.

So, I want to know how to make this work. But I am asking for something more than that. I have this problem, or an analogous problem, all the time. After several years of using R, I still have it a couple of times a week. I don't know how many steps of evaluation R is going to take on any given occasion. I hand a function an object name, and the function treats it as a string. I hand a function a string, and the R function converts it to a symbol and tries to evaluate it. Here, I don't understand why the `save` function does not save the object I gave it, and then give it back with `load`.

I've read the discussions on scoping in ten different R books, from Chambers "Software for Data Analysis" to Wickham's "Advanced R." Twice. Four times in some cases. I know about the four environments of a function, and the difference between the call stack and the chain of environmental parents. And yet, it is clear that I am missing something basic. It is not just that I don't know why `save` does not take a name in its `...` argument and save it as an object (unless the problem is at the load end). I don't know how I *can* know. The function description says, of the `...`s, "the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character strings)." So why is it saving a name as a string? Or why is load returning a string, if save saved an object? And how could I predict that?

Experienced R programmers, I know you can tell in advance how a given R function is going to treat one of its arguments. You know how far it will be evaluated. You can make it go as far as you want it to, and then STOP. You don't have to write `str()`'s into your functions every time you want to figure out what the heck it thinks its arguments mean. How do you do it?

Bloody "R Inferno". It's an **understatement.**

Comment: Just use load(file=fileString). Don't have to assign it back to defaultPacks

Comment: Load returns "A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly."  So in this case it returned a string "defaultPacks"

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for clarifying this. In any case the return value is not what the OP seems to be expecting; and by assigning this return value to `defaultPacks` the command becomes useless, as it redefines the variable that has just been loaded.

Comment: @RHertel, you wanna tackle his 2nd qn? ;)

Comment: As @chinsoon12 correctly pointed out `defaultPacks <- load(file=fileString)` is wrong, you just need `load(file=fileString)` since `load` function automatically re-creates the stored variables into the environment

Comment: @RHertel Qn2 is out of my league...upvote Martin!

Comment: this is why RTFM is so important. and this question would be interesting and helpful without all the commentary and fluff. you cannot just _will_ a language to work as you expect--this will _always_ lead to frustration. RTFM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of seeing the problem is to note that the value of `defaultPacks` changes from before to after these operations.

```
> fname = tempfile()
> orig = defaultPacks = c("AER", "plyr", "dplyr")
> save(defaultPacks, file=fname)
> defaultPacks = load(fname)
> identical(orig, defaultPacks)
[1] FALSE
```

The problem starts with an understanding of what `save()` does. From `?save`, the object that is saved is named `defaultPacks` and it has value `c("AER", "plyr", "dplyr")`. `save()` could save multiple objects, each with a name and associated value, so it somehow has to save the name of each object.

`load()` restores the objects that `save()` has written, and returns (from `?load`) a "character vector of the names of objects created". In this case `load()` restores (creates in the global environment) the symbol `defaultPacks`, populates it with the character vector of default packages, and returns the name (i.e., character vector of length 1 "defaultPacks") of the object(s) it has restored. The return value then overwrites the restored value, and we have `defaultPacks = "defaultPacks"`.

`install.packages` doesn't do anything fancy with it's first argument, which from `?install.packages` is a "character vector of the names of packages whose current versions should be downloaded". The character vector happens to be the symbol `defaultPacks`, but the error comes from the value of the symbol, which is the character vector `"defaultPacks"`.

`save()` and `load()` more or less have to work the way they do to support multiple objects. On the other hand `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` (ok, why *read* instead of *load*?) have a contract to save a single object. The name of the saved object does not need to be stored to be able to recover the values associated with it. So `saveRDS(defaultPacks, fname); defaultPacks = readRDS(fname)` works, and in particular the value of `defaultPacks` before and after this series of operations remains unchanged.

```
> orig = defaultPacks = c("AER", "plyr", "dplyr")
> saveRDS(defaultPacks, fname)
> defaultPacks = readRDS(fname)
> identical(orig, defaultPacks)
[1] TRUE
```

Without meaning to be too much of a jerk, the answer to the question "Experienced R programmers...how do you do it?" the answer is implied by the `?` above -- by carefully reading the manual. Also, there are not that many places in base R code where evaluation is non-standards -- formulas and `library` are the main culprits -- so recognizing what the problem is *not* can help to focus on what is actually going on.